# TreeNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, comparable, treenode

i am trying to write a method that returns the parent for the specified node (BST), i keep getting this:

```
TreeNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Here is the method (is located almost at the end!) - (the whole code):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import chapter27.AbstractTree;

public class Test<E extends Comparable<E>> 
extends AbstractTree<E> {
protected TreeNode<E> root;
protected int size = 0;

/** Create a default binary tree */
public Test() {
}

/** Create a binary tree from an array of objects */
public Test(E[] objects) {
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
  insert(objects[i]);
}

@Override /** Returns true if the element is in the tree */
public boolean search(E e) {
TreeNode<E> current = root; // Start from the root

while (current != null) {
  if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
    current = current.left;
  }
  else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
    current = current.right;
  }
  else // element matches current.element
    return true; // Element is found
}

return false;
}

@Override /** Insert element o into the binary tree
* Return true if the element is inserted successfully */
public boolean insert(E e) {
if (root == null)
  root = createNewNode(e); // Create a new root
else {
  // Locate the parent node
  TreeNode<E> parent = null;
  TreeNode<E> current = root;
  while (current != null)
    if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
      parent = current;
      current = current.left;
    }
    else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
      parent = current;
      current = current.right;
    }
    else
      return false; // Duplicate node not inserted

  // Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
  if (e.compareTo(parent.element) < 0)
    parent.left = createNewNode(e);
  else
    parent.right = createNewNode(e);
}

size++;
return true; // Element inserted
}

protected TreeNode<E> createNewNode(E e) {
return new TreeNode<E>(e);
}

@Override /** Inorder traversal from the root*/
public void inorder() {
inorder(root);
}

/** Inorder traversal from a subtree */
protected void inorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
if (root == null) return;
inorder(root.left);
System.out.print(root.element + " ");
inorder(root.right);
}

@Override /** Postorder traversal from the root */
public void postorder() {
postorder(root);
}

/** Postorder traversal from a subtree */
protected void postorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
if (root == null) return;
postorder(root.left);
postorder(root.right);
System.out.print(root.element + " ");
}

@Override /** Preorder traversal from the root */
public void preorder() {
preorder(root);
}

/** Preorder traversal from a subtree */
protected void preorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
if (root == null) return;
System.out.print(root.element + " ");
preorder(root.left);
preorder(root.right);
}

/** This inner class is static, because it does not access 
  any instance members defined in its outer class */
    public static class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
        public E element;
        public TreeNode<E> left;
        public TreeNode<E> right;
        public TreeNode<E> parent;

        public TreeNode(E e) {
            element = e;
        }
    }

@Override /** Get the number of nodes in the tree */
public int getSize() {
return size;
}

/** Returns the root of the tree */
public TreeNode<E> getRoot() {
return root;
}

/** Returns a path from the root leading to the specified element */
public java.util.ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> path(E e) {
java.util.ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> list =
  new java.util.ArrayList<TreeNode<E>>();
TreeNode<E> current = root; // Start from the root

while (current != null) {
  list.add(current); // Add the node to the list
  if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
    current = current.left;
  }
  else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
    current = current.right;
  }
  else
    break;
}

return list; // Return an array of nodes
}

@Override /** Delete an element from the binary tree.
* Return true if the element is deleted successfully
* Return false if the element is not in the tree */
public boolean delete(E e) {
// Locate the node to be deleted and also locate its parent node
TreeNode<E> parent = null;
TreeNode<E> current = root;
while (current != null) {
  if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
    parent = current;
    current = current.left;
  }
  else if (e.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
    parent = current;
    current = current.right;
  }
  else
    break; // Element is in the tree pointed at by current
}

if (current == null)
  return false; // Element is not in the tree

// Case 1: current has no left children
if (current.left == null) {
  // Connect the parent with the right child of the current node
  if (parent == null) {
    root = current.right;
  }
  else {
    if (e.compareTo(parent.element) < 0)
      parent.left = current.right;
    else
      parent.right = current.right;
  }
}
else {
  // Case 2: The current node has a left child
  // Locate the rightmost node in the left subtree of
  // the current node and also its parent
  TreeNode<E> parentOfRightMost = current;
  TreeNode<E> rightMost = current.left;

  while (rightMost.right != null) {
    parentOfRightMost = rightMost;
    rightMost = rightMost.right; // Keep going to the right
  }

  // Replace the element in current by the element in rightMost
  current.element = rightMost.element;

  // Eliminate rightmost node
  if (parentOfRightMost.right == rightMost)
    parentOfRightMost.right = rightMost.left;
  else
    // Special case: parentOfRightMost == current
    parentOfRightMost.left = rightMost.left;     
}

size--;
return true; // Element inserted
}

@Override /** Obtain an iterator. Use inorder. */
public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
return new InorderIterator();
}

// Inner class InorderIterator
private class InorderIterator implements java.util.Iterator<E> {
// Store the elements in a list
private java.util.ArrayList<E> list =
  new java.util.ArrayList<E>();
private int current = 0; // Point to the current element in list

public InorderIterator() {
  inorder(); // Traverse binary tree and store elements in list
}

/** Inorder traversal from the root*/
private void inorder() {
  inorder(root);
}

/** Inorder traversal from a subtree */
private void inorder(TreeNode<E> root) {
  if (root == null)return;
  inorder(root.left);
  list.add(root.element);
  inorder(root.right);
}

@Override /** More elements for traversing? */
public boolean hasNext() {
  if (current < list.size())
    return true;

  return false;
}

@Override /** Get the current element and move to the next */
public E next() {
  return list.get(current++);
}

@Override /** Remove the current element */
public void remove() {
  delete(list.get(current)); // Delete the current element
  list.clear(); // Clear the list
  inorder(); // Rebuild the list
}
}

/** Remove all elements from the tree */
public void clear() {
root = null;
size = 0;
}


public TreeNode<E> getParent(TreeNode<E> node) {
    TreeNode<E> parent = null;
    TreeNode<E> current = root;

    while (current != null) {
        if (((Comparable<E>)node.element).compareTo((E)current.element) < 0) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.left;
        } else if (((Comparable<E>) node.element).compareTo((E)current.element) > 0) {
            parent = current;
            current = current.right;
        } else {
            break;
        }
     }

    size++;
    return parent;

}

public ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> getPath(TreeNode<E> node) {

    return null;

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] numbers = {2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7};
        Test<Integer> list = new Test<Integer>(numbers);

        System.out.print("Inorder (sorted): ");
        list.inorder();
        System.out.print("\nPostorder: ");
        list.postorder();
        System.out.print("\nPreorder: ");
        list.preorder();
        System.out.print("\nThe number of nodes is " + list.getSize());
        System.out.print("\nIs 1 in the tree? " + 
                  list.search(1));

        System.out.print("\nA path from the root to 5 is: ");
        java.util.ArrayList<Test.TreeNode<Integer>>  path 
          = list.path(5);
        for (int i = 0; path != null && i < path.size(); i++)
          System.out.print(path.get(i).element + " ");


        TreeNode<Integer> node = new TreeNode<Integer>(5); 
        System.out.print("\nThe parent of " + 5 + ": " + list.getParent(node));

    }
}
```

Comment: Is `TreeNode` your own class? If so, please show it.

Comment: TreeNode is the name of an interface.  That interface does not implement Comparable.  The underlying object class *might* implement Comparable, in which case casting to Comparable will work.  If not, casting to Comparable will throw a ClassCastException.

Comment: (But checking a couple of the classes that implement TreeNode, they don't appear to implement Comparable, so very likely you are SOL.)

Comment: to jon Skeet i will show the whole code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that while the generic parameter of TreeNode is Comparable, the class itself is not.

Change this:

```
public static class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
```

To this:

```
public static class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<TreeNode<E>> {
```

Or if you don't require the generic type to also be Comparable:

```
public static class TreeNode<E> implements Comparable<TreeNode<E>> {
```

Once you make this change, you won't need the cast.

Comment: Thanks for that. But i still getting: The parent of 5:TreeNode@471e30. can you explain me why?!!

Comment: Well, you should override the `toString()` method if you want sensible output when printed. Let me know if that doesn't help

Comment: After a several hours with this i am going to give up! I am simply tired! How to use toString() here?

Comment: I tried like this: System.out.print("\nThe parent of " + 4 + ": " + node.toString(4)); and i get this: The parent of 4: null - Why?

Comment: You should not have a method called toString that takes a parameter - too confusing. I would have thought you would code something like: `System.out.print("The parent of " + 4 + ": " + node.get(4).getParent());`. Also, `getParent()` should not take a parameter - the parent is the parent. I think the design needs a rethink.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

> ```
>        if (((Comparable<E>)node.element).compareTo((E)current) < 0) {
> ```

You are comparing the element at `node` with `current`. But `current` is a `TreeNode`, not the element stored there.

You probably need:

```
if (((Comparable<E>)node.element).compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
```

Comment: i got this (trying your solution): The parent of 5: TreeNode@118f375 !! Why?!

Comment: You are printing the node itself, not the item stored there.

Comment: But the method is correct!!.. i don't understand! (I showed the whole code!)

Comment: Even if the method is correct, you're printing the node of a tree. If you have not defined how a tree node should look like as a string (by overriding the toString method) what you'll see is TreeNode@(hex digits). I suggest you print the item stored at the node rather than the node itself.

Comment: to be honest I do not know how to do it! i spent all night with this code trying a several solutions and in the end: none of them works! i stuck!