# Casting with Comparable

Tags: java, casting, tree, binary-tree, comparable

I'm trying to find the minimum value of a node within a tree, and in order to detect whether something has smaller value, I'm using the `compareTo()` function as seen below:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public static Object min(TreeNode t)
   {
      if(t == null) {
         return null;
      }
      
      Comparable<TreeNode> min = (Comparable<TreeNode>) t;
      
      if(t.getLeft() != null) {
         Comparable<TreeNode> leftMin = (Comparable<TreeNode>) min(t.getLeft());
         
         if( ((Comparable<TreeNode>)leftMin).compareTo( (Comparable<TreeNode>)min) < 0) {
            min = leftMin;
         }
      }
      
      if(t.getRight() != null) {
         Comparable<TreeNode> rightMin = (Comparable<TreeNode>) min(t.getRight());
         
         if( ((Comparable<TreeNode>)rightMin).compareTo( (Comparable<TreeNode>)min) < 0) {
            min = rightMin;
         }
      }
      
      return min;
   }
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:
`error: incompatible types: Comparable<TreeNode> cannot be converted to TreeNode`
at the if statement.

I was told that the Object must be cast to Comparable in order to call compareTo()

And I have tried looking at this similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899952/treenode-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-comparable), but **I don't have access to change the TreeNode Class**

TreeNode Class:

```
public class TreeNode
{
   private Object value; 
   private TreeNode left, right;
   
   public TreeNode(Object initValue)
   { 
      value = initValue; 
      left = null; 
      right = null; 
   }

   /*methods*/

}
```

And I have also tried: `if(leftMin.compareTo(min) < 0)` however that yields the same error.

Do you know how to properly cast and convert the following classes?

Comment: You wouldn't need any casting at all if you used generics correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, you can use the comparable interface, which will require you to implement the `compareTo` method.

The compare to implementation details can be found in the java se docs:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
> negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
> than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So we can change your class to something like what is shown below (**Note:** I recommend converting value to an int or any other primitive type):

```
 class TreeNode implements Comparable<TreeNode> {
        // recommend to convert value to int or any other primitive type
        private Object value; 
        private TreeNode left, right;
       
        public TreeNode(Object initValue) { 
            value = initValue; 
            left = null; 
            right = null; 
        }
       
        // if value is int, just use ==, < and > 
        // i.e. this.value == o.value, this.value < o.value and so on ...
        @Override
        public int compareTo(TreeNode o) {
            if (this.value.equals(o.value)) return 0;
            else if (this.value.hashCode() < o.value.hashCode()) return -1;
            else return 1;
        }
    
       /*methods*/
}
```

Then you don't really need to do the casting in the `min` method. (**Note:** The implementation below is not actually correct - won't give you the min. It's just shown as to how the implementation would change after implementing the comparable interface).

```
// This method is not actually correct (i.e. won't actually find the min), 
// but showing how it would change after using the comparable interface 
// on the tree node class. 
public TreeNode min(TreeNode t) {
    if(t == null) {
     return null;
    }
  
    TreeNode min =  t;
  
    if(t.getLeft() != null) {
        TreeNode leftMin = min.getLeft();
     
        if(leftMin.compareTo(min) < 0) {
            min = leftMin;
        }
    }
  
    if(t.getRight() != null) {
        TreeNode rightMin = min.getRight();
        
        if( rightMin.compareTo(min) < 0) {
            min = rightMin;
        }
    }
  
    return min;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to change the class

Comment: In that case, try extending the `TreeNode` class (subclass it with the `extends` keyword) or create a new class with the `TreeNode` as a member variable and then implement the `comparable` interface for that class. Write your minimum finding logic, based on that new class.

Answer (score 0):

The class `TreeNode` must implement the `Comparable` interface:

```
public class TreeNode implements Comparable<TreeNode> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TreeNode other) {
        ...  // maybe compare 'initValue' here
    }
}
```

also not sure if it is so good to cast `TreeNode` to `Comparable`, I would prefer to work
without casting at all (e.g. `public static TreeNode min(TreeNode t)`)

---

Edit: probably it was meant to cast `initValue` to `Comparable` so it can be compared - not very (type-) safe having it declared as `Object` in that case.

---

Edit after question changed. Since `TreeNode` cannot be changed, I think you must clearly split nodes and values, probably something like below (must be completed):

```
public static TreeNode min(TreeNode node) {
    ...
    TreeNode minNode = node;
    Comparable<?> minValue = (Comparable<?>) minNode.getValue(); // guessed method name

    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        TreeNode leftMin = min(t.getLeft());
        Comparable<?> leftValue = (Comparable<?>) leftMin.getValue();
        if (leftValue.compareTo(minValue) < 0) {
            minNode = leftNode;
            minValue = leftValue;
        }
    ...
```

This requires that instances in `Value` implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @Andrei answer edited to reflect changes made to question, but also consider [m_vemuri answer and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094592/13510609)